# many-to-many in Laravel and select data by condition of relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-relations

I have next tables in my Laravel project
Posts

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | post1 |
| 2 | post2 |
| 3 | post3 |
| 4 | post4 |
| 5 | post5 |

Tags

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | tag1 |
| 2 | tag2 |
| 3 | tag3 |
| 4 | tag4 |
| 5 | tag5 |

post_tag

| post_id | tag_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 |

in other words

| post | tags |
| --- | --- |
| post1 | tag1 tag2 tag3 tag5 |
| post2 | tag2 |
| post3 | tag2 tag3 tag5 |
| post4 | tag2 tag3 tag4 tag5 |
| post5 | tag3 tag4 |

I have query - something like that: `+tag2+tag3-tag4` (that can be different length; + = include; - = except from result)
How can I get post ONLY with tags which have "+" before and except tags with "-" before?

Using an example table:
post1 (has tag2 **AND** tag3 **AND NOT** tag4)
post3 (has tag2 **AND** tag3 **AND NOT** tag4)

I try to use next

```
$posts = Post::query()
->with('tags')
->whereHas('tags', function ($query) {
 $query->whereIn('tags.name', ['tag2', 'tag3'])
    ->whereNnotIn('tags.name', ['tag4']);
})
->get();
```

But it doesn't give me needed result
Can somebody help me with that??

Thanks!

Comment: doesn't give me needed result means ? any erorr or returning empty ?

Comment: it select posts which has only one of the tag: tag2 or tag3 BUT I need ONLY with tag2 AND tag3 AND NOT tag4